# Server running on localhost causes bug while exact same code hosted works

Tags: node.js

I'm getting a strange bug where my locally hosted version of a node server is causing a rendering problem. Essentially I'm trying to retrieve highscores and the table isn't showing up on screen.

I have literally copy+pasted the hosted version of my server into a file on my local machine and run it with node myserver.js so I know there is no difference between the two. I'm not getting any network or js errors when requesting from either and the results from the local and hosted versions of the server are identical.

What would cause this and how would I go about fixing it?

server.js

```
// BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================

// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app        = express();

// configure app
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port

var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://xxxxxx:xxxxxxxx.mongolab.com:xxxxxx'); // connect to our database
var User = require('./app/models/user');

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================

// create our router
var router = express.Router();

// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // log everytime someone hits the server
    //console.log('Something hit the server');
    next();
});

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

router.route('/scores')
    .options(function(req, res){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    })
    .get(function(req, res){
        var query = User.find({}).sort({currentHighscore: -1}).limit(10);
        query.select('currentHighscore username');
        query.exec(function(err, scores){
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.json(scores);
        });
    });

router.route('/score/:username')
    .options(function(req, res){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT,DELETE");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        res.json({message:'work'});
    })
    .put(function(req, res){
        User.find({username: req.params.username}, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            else {
                user[0].currentHighscore = req.body.newHighscore;
                user[0].save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.send(err);
                    }else {
                        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                        res.json({ message: 'Updated Highscore for '+req.params.username });
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    })
    .delete(function(req, res){
        User.find({username: req.params.username}, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            } else{
                user[0].currentHighscore = 0;
                user[0].save(function(err){
                    if(err){
                        res.send(err)
                    } else{
                        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                        res.json({ message: 'Reset highscore for ' + req.params.username + ' to 0'})
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    });

router.route('/position/:username').
    get(function(req, res){
        User.find({username: req.params.username}, function(err, user) {
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            }else {
                var userHighscore = user[0].currentHighscore;
                var query = User.count({}).where('currentHighscore').gt(userHighscore);
                query.exec(function(err, count){
                    count = count + 1;
                    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    res.json(count);
                });
            }
        });
    });


// on routes that end in /users
// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/users')
    .options(function(req, res){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
        res.json({message:'work'});
    })
    // create a user (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/users)
    .post(function(req, res) {
        User.find({username: req.body.newUsername}, function(err, user) {
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            }else if(user.length == 0){
                var user = new User();      // create a new instance of the User model
                user.username = req.body.newUsername;  // set the users name (comes from the request)

                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.send(err);
                    }else {
                        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                        res.json({ created: true });    
                    }

                });
            } else{
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.json({ created: false, reason:'This username is taken'})
            }
        });




    })

    // get all the users (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/users)
    .get(function(req, res) {
        User.find(function(err, users) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.json(users);
        });
    });

// on routes that end in /users/:user_id
// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/users/:username')

    // get the user with that id
    .get(function(req, res) {
        User.find({username: req.params.username}, function(err, user) {
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
    })

    // delete the user with this id
    .delete(function(req, res) {
        User.remove({
            _id: req.params.user_id
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });


// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================

// OPENSHIFT PICKUP CHANGE
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 1234;
app.listen( port, ipaddress, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port '+port);
});


// app.listen(port);
// console.log('Server is running on port: ' + port);
```

Comment: More details about the rendering problem so we might have some idea which are of the code is having the issue?  Also, browsers have some different restrictions that they apply to localHost access.

Comment: When you run it locally, where is the mongodb instance? Do you have access to it? The collection has the data?

Comment: Just Curious...do you have data in mongodb collection?

Comment: The program is a game, it is supposed to render a scoreboard and while the code takes exactly the same route the scoreboard doesn't render. 

I have a free mongdb hosted online by a company. Both the local and hosted versions of my server access the same db. As I said, the returned data is identical in both scenarios. All I ever change is where the app it sending its requests. Ie www.myhost/api/scores or 127.0.0.1/api/scores